# Why do some Data.List.Split functions use `Int` and others `Integral a`?

Tags: haskell

Here are the type signatures of [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/latest/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v%3achunksOf) and [`splitPlaces`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/latest/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v%3asplitPlaces) from `Data.List.Split`:

```
chunksOf :: Int -> [e] -> [[e]]
splitPlaces :: Integral a => [a] -> [e] -> [[e]]
```

Why do some functions (like `chunksOf`) use `Int` while others (like `splitPlaces`) use the more generic `Integral a`?

Comment: Good question!  I don't see any particular good reason from an interface standpoint -- maybe just slightly easier implementation.  Could use standardization.  Which one of the two is better depends on outlook, disagreements will abound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this answer, I try to look at the historical reasons for the inconsistent interface. *Summary*: It seems that Brent made some functions more generic on the fly to help formulating QuickCheck properties.

## Why is `splitPlaces` generic?

It looks as if Brent generalized the type of `splitPlaces` to make it easier to introduce QuickCheck properties for that function. The QuickCheck properties use newtype wrappers to control test case generation, and with the `Integral a` constraint, `splitPlaces` could look through this newtype wrapper for the arithmetic operations. See also:

- [The patch](http://hub.darcs.net/byorgey/split/patch/20081220184627-1e371)
  that generalizes the type of `splitPlaces` and introduces the QuickCheck properties.
- [The QuickCheck documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.6/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#g:11) about these newtype wrappers.

However, here is one of the properties about `splitPlaces`:

```
prop_splitPlaces_preserve :: [NonNegative Integer] -> [Elt] -> Bool
prop_splitPlaces_preserve ps l = concat (splitPlaces ps' l) == genericTake (sum ps') l
  where ps' = map unNN ps
```

Note that QuickCheck automatically generates the list `ps` which is converted by `map unNN ps` before being passed to `splitPlaces`. The `unNN` function removes the `NonNegative` wrapper, so `splitPlaces` does not have to deal with the `NonNegative` wrapper itself. However, it receives an argument of type `[Integer]` instead of `[Int]`, so it still needs to be generic in the numeric type.

## What's the point of using `[NonNegative Integer]` instead of `[NonNegative Int]`?

I suspect that the property is false for `[Int]` because of arithmetic overflows when computing the sum. The property might even be falsifiable by QuickCheck because the `Arbitrary [NonNegative Integer]` instance will ultimately delegate to [`arbitrarySizedBoundedIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.6/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3aarbitrarySizedBoundedIntegral) which can generate very large values.

I guess that using  `[NonNegative Integer]` instead circumvents this problem in two ways:

1. With `Integer`, no overflows can occur.
2. The `Arbitrary Integer` instance delegates to [`arbitrarySizedIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.6/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3aarbitrarySizedIntegral) which only generates small values.

So I guess that the reason for allowing arbitrary Integral types is that the QuickCheck property would fail for `Int` but succeeds for `Integer`.

## Why is `chunksOf` not generic?

The properties for `chunksOf` use pattern matching to remove the newtype wrappers. See also:

- [The patch](http://hub.darcs.net/byorgey/split/patch/20081220181828-1e371) that introduces properties for `splitEvery`.
- [The patch](http://hub.darcs.net/byorgey/split/patch/20120723165447-1e371) that renames `splitEvery` to `chunksOf`.

Here is one of the properties about `chunksOf`:

```
prop_chunksOf_all_n :: Positive Int -> NonEmptyList Elt -> Bool
prop_chunksOf_all_n (Positive n) (NonEmpty l) = all ((==n) . length) (init $ chunksOf n l)
```

Note that this property matches on the arguments that are automatically generated by QuickCheck and passes them to `chunksOf` without the newtype wrapper. For the arguments necessary for testing `chunksOf`, this is easy to do, because the numbers are not nested in other types. Compare with `prop_splitPlaces_preserve` above, where converting `[NonNegative Integer]` to `[Integer]` or `[Int]` requires something more complicated than just pattern matching.

The difference between `Arbitrary Int` and `Arbitrary Integer` doesn't matter here, because the property does not involve any operations that can trigger an arithmetic overflow.